# Validation accuracy in Keras not consistent

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on a binary classification model (CNN) and I have separated my classes in different folders in /data/train and /data/validation accordingly

Last layers:

```
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get this message which indicates that classes are correctly linked to my data:

> Found 638 images belonging to 2 classes. Found 214 images belonging to
>   2 classes.

The weird thing is that I get really good val_acc:

> loss: 0.2453 - acc: 0.8858 - val_loss: 0.2000 - val_acc: 0.9231

Which does not seem valid. In random tests in 15 images of all the dataset produce the same result: 1 for `model.predict_classes(x)`

Why is val_acc so high?

Comment: Did you check whether those 15 images are indeed from the same class? Since your dataset is quite small, you can manually check all the results to see if the validation images are classified correctly.

Comment: @pyan They are definitely from different classes. And in fact it makes sense that the classification does not work. The thing is why I get so good accuracy results. It makes me think that there is something important I am missing here.

Comment: Are your training and validation images divided evenly for the 2 classes? i.e. Does each class contain similar number of images?

Comment: @pyan They are almost even: 350 and 420 images accordingly. And yes, both classes contain almost identical images with small differences. But this should not be the case, right? The validation set is annotated.

Comment: What is the overall prediction result of the entire validation set? Still all 1s?